# Python - How to convert unicode to hexadecimal

Tags: python, unicode, hex

How do I convert unicode (Chinese  characters) into hexadecimal using Python? I have been searching around for few days, but no luck.

Example:

> Before convert: 耳环测试
>
> After convert: 8033 73AF 6D4B 8BD5

I get the result using the following unicode online convertor tool:
http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

But I didn't manage to get it in my python code.

I tried using "binascii.hexlify(data)" but the result is "e880b3e78eafe6b58be8af95". I didn't manage to get the 4 digits hexadecimal.

my code:

```
s1 = "耳环测试"
s2 = binascii.hexlify(s1)
print s2 # Result: e880b3e78eafe6b58be8af95
```

I am using python 2.7 (Google App Engine). How do I convert "e880b3e78eafe6b58be8af95" to "8033 73AF 6D4B 8BD5" ?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

Joel

Answer (score 0):

`8033 73AF 6D4B 8BD5` are the UTF-16 code points, python gives you the UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Uriel! Do you know how do I get UTF-16 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that in-code, but you could save the required string in a file, and open it like `open(file, encoding="utf-16-le")`, then read the string and use `.encode('utf-16')`.